# Choosing hardware specifications for photodetection

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, adc

If I plan to use an ADC of 16-bit resolution, does this have to match with the bits of the microcontroller I use? For instance, the Arduino Micro is 8-bit which is to process digital data from the ADC. Should I choose a microcontroller of 16-bits?

Comment: If you use serial output, you can manage 2 byte words with any bit CPU

Comment: No, you do not need to. But it might more work for the MCU to do math on the 16-bit result from the ADC.

Comment: back in the 70's we used 12 bit ADC's when there only 8 bit 6800's  and now there are 24 bit ADC's What does that tell you?

Answer (score 1):

The 8-bit Arduino has no problem processing 16-bit data. It just has to do it in two 8-bit chunks. The compiler knows how to do this for you so you can just process 16-bit data like normal in your code.

You might end up choosing a 16-bit or 32-bit microcontroller anyway for other reasons. But you don't have to.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Choose your CPU based on processor load and data calculations req’d , cost&performance not on just on data word size alone.

Double precision or floating point math is a feature if needed.

More important is getting EMI controlled on the sensor so you get S/N ratio required with over 63 dB dynamic range implied and TBD unknown noise sources.